# Find all nonnegative integers n, that satisfy the equation P(n, 2) = P(4n − 6, 1)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

I have the equation P(n, 2) = P(4n - 6, 1) and I need to find all non negative integers which satisfy it.  I understand that this equation can also be written as

n!/(n-2)! = (4n-6)!/(4n-5)!

and that the correct answers are 2 and 3.  However, I am not sure how to arrive at 2 and 3 without just blindly guessing and plugging in numbers.

Comment: Try to simplify the terms

Comment: I plugged it into wolfram alpha which showed me that the equation could also be written as n^2+6 = 5 n but I am lost on the algebra to actually do that myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $n! = n(n - 1)(n - 2)!$ and that $(4n - 6)! = (4n - 6)(4n - 5)!$.  Thus,

\begin{align*}
P(n, 2) & = P(4n - 6, 1)\\
\frac{n!}{(n - 2)!} & = \frac{(4n - 6)!}{(4n - 5)!}\\
\frac{n(n - 1)(n - 2)!}{(n - 2)!} & = \frac{(4n - 6)(4n - 5)!}{(4n - 5)!}\\
n(n - 1) & = 4n - 6\\
n^2 - n & = 4n - 6\\
n^2 - 5n + 6 & = 0
\end{align*}
I assume you now see how to complete the problem.

Comment: Am I correct that I need to use the quadratic formula to get to 2 and 3?

Comment: That would be one way of solving it.  However, you can factor it.  Observe that $6 = -2 \cdot -3$ and that $-5 = -2 + -3$.